# How can I upgrade ubuntu server 14.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-18.04

I want to upgrade ubuntu server **14.04 LTS** to **18.04 LTS** without upgrading 16.04 LTS. can you please help me for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No. You can not upgrade.**

Ubuntu does have LTS→LTS upgrades, allowing you to skip intermediate non-LTS releases...
But you can't skip intermediate LTS releases. You have to go via 16.04.

Unless you want to do a fresh install of 18.04 on release.

I should also note that the LTS upgrade pathways are usually only available sometime after the main release. So don't expect to be able to upgrade from 16.04 on the day of 18.04's release.

Reference post - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015728/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-14-04-to-18-04